# Response Object for Spring Boot API's

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing an application with Spring boot.Now I have developed the API's and I want to return the JSON Output for the API's. So how do I create the response class & convert it to JSON? Will it be common class or do I have to create a response class for every API?

Comment: how have you developed your API's, using spring? If yes, then spring will automatically convert it to json. It internally uses Jackson to do this

Answer (score 4):

Well assuming you're making a spring boot web application with @RequestMapping, you can just return your objects and Spring will automatically convert them to JSON. You can also return a [ResponseEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) object if you wish to include headers or modify to HTTPStatus code

I recommend checking out [the spring boot starter guide for RESTful webservices](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

Comment: "You can just return your objects", I was asking about these? Do I have to create these API specific, So I have 100 API, then do I have to create 100 Response Classes or should I create one common response class & feed data to it. I am hoping to do later one. Can you refer me an link on where such implementation is implemented?